# Cannot pin documents to taskbar items that already exist

Tags: windows-7, taskbar

On a Windows 7 box, I suddenly cannot pin documents to pinned taskbar applications.  Any idea how to fix this?

What I've done to try to fix this:

1. Rebooted
2. Recreated all pinned taskbar applications

When I try to pin a document to an application that is pinned to the taskbar, nothing new appears when right-clicking on the pinned application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick is to create the folder:

- `%APPDATA%\Microsoft\Windows\Recent`

Once this is done, Windows 7 will automatically create subfolders:

- `%APPDATA%\Microsoft\Windows\Recent\AutomaticDestinations`
- `%APPDATA%\Microsoft\Windows\Recent\CustomDestinations`

which are required to pin items to taskbar applications.

Note that Windows will not create `%APPDATA%\Microsoft\Windows\Recent` on its own.  You have to create that folder manually, if it does not exist.

I hope this helps others.